# Linux group 998,what does it mean?

Tags: linux, docker, laradock

Ubuntu 20 LTS, Installed laradock,

in Ubuntu

```
$ pwd
/root/Docker

$ ls
blog laradock

$ rsync -a /media/sf_code/blog  . && chmod -R 755 blog
$ cd laracock
$ docker-compose exec --user=root  workspace bash
```

in docker

```
> ll
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  4 laradock laradock 4096 Nov 12 06:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x  1 root     root     4096 Nov 12 02:30 ../
drwxr-xr-x 12 root          998 4096 Nov 12 03:09 blog/
drwxr-xr-x 74 laradock laradock 4096 Nov 12 06:35 laradock/
```

what does `998` mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: It just means there's no entry for group 998 in `/etc/groups`, so it's shown numerically instead of translated to a name.

Comment: @Barmar I'd rather suggest [sf] since the [tag:docker] tag explicitly refers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4th column is the group id. It there is an entry in `/etc/group` with this id, then the group name will be printed otherwise the id.

The your example the group id of folder `blog` is 998 but no group exist inside the container with this id. Mapping a folder to a docker container does not change owner or group.

Some explanation can be found [here](https://linoxide.com/linux-command/20-ls-command-linux/)